# Create x509 Certificate from String private key

Tags: java, certificate, private-key

I have private key in string format as below

```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```

now i want to convert it into x509 certificate, i am using below code.

```
localByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                paramString.getBytes());
        CertificateFactory localCertificateFactory = CertificateFactory
                .getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate localX509Certificate = (X509Certificate) localCertificateFactory
                .generateCertificate(localByteArrayInputStream);
        localByteArrayInputStream.close();
localByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                paramString.getBytes());
        CertificateFactory localCertificateFactory = CertificateFactory
                .getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate localX509Certificate = (X509Certificate) localCertificateFactory
                .generateCertificate(localByteArrayInputStream);
        localByteArrayInputStream.close();

 (X509Certificate)localCertificateFactory.generateCertificate(localByteArrayInputStream);
      localByteArrayInputStream.close();
```

I have tried many ways but could not understand how to do it. in this scenario i am getting below error.

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:104)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
```

Comment: A 'certificate' is generally a wrapper around a public key. How are you going to generate a public key from a private key of some sort?

Comment: localX509Certificate.getPublicKey() using this the verification is done.

Comment: You have a pkcs8 private key. You want an X.509 certificate. Those are two very different things with no natural "conversion" from one to the other. You could 1) extract the public key from your private key(I checked, it contains the necessary fields), and 2) create a self-signed X.509 certificate from the public and private keys. The public key is contained in the certificate and the private is used to sign it.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error. as per generateCertificate "In the case of a certificate factory for X.509 certificates, the certificate provided in inStream must be DER-encoded andmay be supplied in binary or printable (Base64) encoding. If thecertificate is provided in Base64 encoding, it must be bounded at the beginning by `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, and must be bounded at the end by `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`."

I added `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`, then it fixed the exception

Comment: You didn't get this doing what the OP did. You had a certificate. He had a private key. Answer is not relevant.